# sql syntax error

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

i've got the following problem:
[image]

here is my sql for the update

```
 public void editEvent(String eventName, String eventCategory, String longitude, String latitude, String pricesFrom, String startDate, String endDate, String eventDescription, String address, String postcode){
    String query = "update `mtgultas`.`Event` SET `Event` VALUES(`eventName` = '"+eventName+"', `eventCategory` =  '"+eventCategory+"', `longitude` =   '"+longitude+"', `latitude` =   '"+latitude+"', `pricesFrom` =   '"+pricesFrom+"', `startDate` =   '"+startDate+"', `endDate` =   '"+endDate+"', `eventDescription` =   '"+eventDescription+"', `address` =   '"+address+"', `postcode` =   '"+postcode+"')";
    db.update(query);
    System.out.println(query);
}
```

what i am trying to do is update the database entry. i can populate my frame with the current details however when i click save to update it has a "paddy"
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using mysql - you can get the correct syntax for an update query from the mysql website - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

At a quick glance, you don't need the `Event values` or the parenthesis.

Comment: hi.when i remoeve event values it still brings the same syntax

Comment: Look at Marcos' reply - that is what your syntax should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You SQL should be something like

```
update `mtgultas`.`Event` SET `eventName` = '"+eventName+"', `eventCategory` =  '"+eventCategory+"', `longitude` =   '"+longitude+"', `latitude` =   '"+latitude+"', `pricesFrom` =   '"+pricesFrom+"', `startDate` =   '"+startDate+"', `endDate` =   '"+endDate+"', `eventDescription` =   '"+eventDescription+"', `address` =   '"+address+"', `postcode` =   '"+postcode+"'"
```

Comment: with the above sql when i update all previous entrys are deleted. e.g. i edit an event close the frame/program reopen and the events have dissapeared apart from the one that i edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
String query = String.format("UPDATE mtgultas.Event SET eventName = '%s', eventCategory = '%s', longitude = '%s', latitude = '%s', pricesFrom = '%s', startDate = '%s', endDate = '%s', eventDescription = '%s', address = '%s', postcode = '%s'",
                    eventName,
                    eventCategory,
                    longitude,
                    latitude,
                    pricesFrom,
                    startDate,
                    endDate,
                    eventDescription,
                    address,
                    postcode);
```

Just FYI, you are missing a `WHERE` clause in your `update` statement. That means, if you execute this statement, it will update all the rows in that table.

Comment: i've got a form that when opened has the data already inserted (blahblah.settext) then the user can edit and the sql is meant to update the db with the new data as of whats in the fields (even though it means all entrys for that event will be updated again) (if that makes sence)

Comment: Okay, but it does sound a little odd to me to update the all rows in the table with the same values. Perhaps, it is better to normalize it and come up with a one-to-many relationship so that you only need to update just one row.

Comment: what i'm going for is that the user may want to update any bit of information and change it from the current value. thats why i'm doing it like this

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be dangerous in order of SQL-injection, never concanate a user-input into an SQL-Query!

Use PreparedStatements instead.